# Usage of had *ed and were in the same sentence

Tags: past-tense, backshifting

So, I have a sentence:

> The amount of workers **had increased** significantly when CNC machines **were** launched.

I wanted to say that when CNC machines were launched (or have been launched, *not sure*), only after that the amount of workers increased.

Is my original sentence correct?

Comment: *Number of workers*, not *amount of workers*. (Amount of work, number of jobs or workers.)

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly cromulent, but it doesn't say what you want it to say.

The *had increased* locates the increase at a time before the time that you are focussing on (which is not expressed). It says that the increase and the launch were at the same time, but it does not clearly say that the increase was after the launch (though that is a possible reading).

There is a possible alternative reading where the launch is the temporal focus, and the increase is located before that; but I would expect a comma before "when", and pragmatically it does not seem likely in this case. But in

> Mr Smith had fallen over when I saw him.

the falling is definitely located in the past relative to the seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Delete *had*. You want the simple past, not the past perfect.

Comment: Not necessarily true.  'had increased' makes perfect sense.